# SQL Server Patching a Mirror configuration

Tags: sql-server, mirror

We're planing to have two SQL servers updated by synchronous database mirroring.  This will include a third environment configured as a witness server.

For standard windows patching - what order should we patch / reboot the servers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order would go like this:

1. Update the secondary server (the one that is not currently serving connections)
2. After it reboots, do a controlled mirroring failover to it
3. Update the primary server (which at this point is no longer serving connections)
4. After it reboots, you can do a controlled failover back to it if you want, but you don't have to.  You can leave the connections running on the secondary box.

Comment: Thanks Brent, how does patching the witness server fit in?

Comment: If the witness server isn't involved in anything else whatsoever, then you can do that first.  I usually see the witness being involved with other SQL Server activities, though - for example, it might be a mirroring partner for another primary server, so it can't be rebooted willy-nilly.  If you're lucky enough to have a dedicated mirroring witness that does nothing else, then you can get it done first, but it doesn't matter whether it's first or last.

Comment: Be careful just leaving the connections running on the secondary box if you don't have a license for it. It's only free if you fail back to the original principal within 45 days.

Comment: Great point, +1 on the comment.  Didn't know about the 45-day limitation - I thought it'd be even shorter than that.

Comment: Thanks Paul and Brent - Am I correct in thinking if all user databases are failed over to the secondary (no active connections to user databases on primary) then the 45 day limitation can be ignored?

Comment: No. The license you have is only for the principal instance - doesn't matter if nothing's using it.